# How to test if a method successfully calls another method in the same class

Tags: mocha.js, jestjs

An over simplified example:

```
class Student {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  goToSchool() {
    if (this.age > 16) {
      this.drive();
    } else {
      this.takeBus();
    }
  }

  drive() {
    //...
  }

  takeBus() {
    //...
  }
}

const john = new Student("John", 15);
john.goToSchool();
```

How can I test if `goToSchool` is able to successfully call the correct method when a certain age is given? Of course, this example is a simplified version of my real-world codebase.

I checked the docs, and found how to mock a function, or mock a class including all its methods, but didn't find how to mock one method in the class while retaining the other methods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```js
class Student {
  private age: number;
  private name: string;
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public goToSchool() {
    if (this.age > 16) {
      this.drive();
    } else {
      this.takeBus();
    }
  }

  public drive() {
    // ...
  }

  public takeBus() {
    // ...
  }
}

export { Student };
```

Unit test:

```js
import { Student } from './';

describe('Student', () => {
  describe('#goToSchool', () => {
    it('should take bus', () => {
      const john = new Student('John', 15);
      const driveSpyOn = jest.spyOn(john, 'drive');
      const takeBusSpyOn = jest.spyOn(john, 'takeBus');
      john.goToSchool();
      expect(takeBusSpyOn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(driveSpyOn).not.toBeCalled();
    });

    it('should drive', () => {
      const john = new Student('Lee', 17);
      const driveSpyOn = jest.spyOn(john, 'drive');
      const takeBusSpyOn = jest.spyOn(john, 'takeBus');
      john.goToSchool();
      expect(driveSpyOn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(takeBusSpyOn).not.toBeCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/54622746/index.spec.ts
  Student
    #goToSchool
      ✓ should take bus (7ms)
      ✓ should drive (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.393s, estimated 3s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/54622746